# Setting a proxy?

Tags: config

Is there a config setting to be able to set a proxy in Craft? WordPress has something like this...

```
define('WP_PROXY_HOST', 'url_here);
define('WP_PROXY_PORT', 'port_here');
```

I was thinking a config setting like the following would be great...

```
'setProxy' => array(
    'host' => 'url_here',
    'port' => 'port_here'
),
```

Thanks,
David

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding any documentation for those constants.  Do you know of any?

Comment: I assume it's for making all of Craft's outbound requests (updating, etc.) point to a proxy server for internet access?

Comment: Yup that's correct. It's not obviously available in the WP codex but http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API has a couple paragraphs. "...WordPress 2.8, compression, cookie support and proxy support were added."

Comment: Example...http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-fetch-file-through-proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible, but I'll add it to our "todo" list!

Comment: Great, thanks! I know this would be useful in a lot of corporate environments.